# Deleting part of array not allowed, why?

Tags: c++

Consider, below program which gives runtime error. Point of this question is to understand memory view and management.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    char* arr = new char[10];
    char* ptr = NULL;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = 'a';
    }
    cout << arr;
    ptr = &arr[5];
    delete ptr;
    cout << arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: None of answer in similar questions provided by you talks about memory view detail, so my question is still unanswered.

Comment: C++14 allows a sort of inverse of what you propose: If you call `new int[a]; new int[b]; new int[c];`, it's allowed to coalesce the allocations into a single call of `::operator new(sizeof(int) * (a + b + c))`, etc.

Comment: The `new` operator make some extra info before the returned address, such the size of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

`new` allocates a block of memory. You can free that memory using `delete`, but you must pass the same address that was returned by `new`. That's how it works. You can't pass arbitrary addresses to `delete`.

Another option is to use `malloc()` and `free()`. These are older function but then you can also use `realloc()` to resize the memory. Then, if you want to delete part of the array, you can resize it to be smaller. **BUT...** you must still copy any data as needed to correctly form the resized array. That is not automatic.